# How to implement business logic using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I want to implement a business logic for my Entity Framework created classes.

But I couldn't figure out how to do so.

This is what I've done so far :

I have the following extension:

```
public static class PropertyExtension
{
    public static void SetPropertyValue(this object obj, string propName, object value)
    {
        obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }

    public static object GetPropValue(this object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        var property = obj.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => string.Equals(p.Name, propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        return property != null ? property.GetValue(obj) : null;
    }
}
```

Secondly, I have Entity Framework created classes:

```
public  partial class ADMIN_PANEL 
 {
    public int AP_REFNO { get; set; }
    public string AP_NAME { get; set; }
    public string AP_PASSWORD { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AP_LAST_LOGIN { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AP_UPDATEDATE { get; set; }         
 }
```

and I have the partial class I've created

```
public bool isEmpty { get { return count == 0; } }
    public int count { get { return _adminPanelArgs.count; } }

    //END PROPERTIES

    #region Constructors
    public ADMIN_PANEL()
    {
        OnFillCompleteHandler += ADMIN_PANELBO_OnFillCompleteHandler;
    }
    #endregion

    void ADMIN_PANELBO_OnFillCompleteHandler(object sender, OnFillArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in e.ADMIN_PANEL[0].GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanWrite == true))
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue(propertyInfo.Name, e.ADMIN_PANEL.First().GetPropValue(propertyInfo.Name));
        }
    }

    public void MyFillAll()
    {
        using (var lobo = new GymProEntities())
        {                         
                _adminPanelArgs.ADMIN_PANEL = lobo.ADMIN_PANEL.ToList();
                OnOnFillCompleteHandler(_adminPanelArgs);                           
        }
    }
}
```

Please ignore any approaches that are not approved, I just want to state my point.

What I would like to do is: have another BusinessLayer class, move the `MyFillAll` method into it, and make my `ADMIN_PANEL.cs` class inherit from it. How do I do that? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a domain layer where you can have all your business logic and pass entities as parameter

```
public class MyDomainService:IMyDomainService
{
    public void MyFillAll(Admin_Panel adminPanel)
    {
        using (var lobo = new GymProEntities())
        {                         
                _adminPanelArgs.ADMIN_PANEL = lobo.ADMIN_PANEL.ToList();
                OnOnFillCompleteHandler(_adminPanelArgs);                           
        }
    }
}
```

i would also suggest inject `lobo` using DI framework.